# How do I print an error raised inside a function?

Tags: python, function, exception

I am writing a code which might raise unknown errors which I'd like to print in order to anticipate them, but if I run the example below nothing gets printed, could someone explain to me why this is the case? Thanks!

```
    def example():
        raise ConnectionError

    try:
        example()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: The exception simply doesn't have any readable error message…?! `print(repr(e))` should give you something…

Comment: You can add a message when you raise the error, try: `raise ConnectionError("This is an alarm")` Now it will display it.

Comment: Ah this is what I did wrong in the first place, thanks! Either the message or repr(e) solves it, thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comment, you need to pass a message when you raise an error.

You can also use the traceback library to help you create and display the full traceback, like this:

```
import traceback

def example():
    raise ConnectionError("This is an alarm")

try:
    example()
except Exception:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xx\OneDrive\BACKUP\Python\testing_free.py", line 7, in <module>
    example()
  File "c:\Users\xx\OneDrive\BACKUP\Python\testing_free.py", line 4, in example
    raise ConnectionError("This is an alarm")
ConnectionError: This is an alarm
```